# How to promote MySQL replica to primary during failover

Tags: server, mysql

In a test environment, I stop a healthy MySQL primary server to simulate a fault and I'm trying to promote the replica to primary.

Both servers:

- run on Ubuntu kinetic with mysql-server 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.10.2.
- are configured with GTID
- have exactly the same MySQL configuration, except for their server-id

Following the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-solutions-switch.html), I've already:

1. disabled the failed primary server on all load balancers
2. waited for the primary server to complete all its transactions:

   Source has sent all binlog to replica; waiting for more updates
3. set the primary server as super R/O
4. dumped all InnoDB databases from the failed primary server as a precaution
5. stopped the IO_THREAD of the replica
6. waited for the replica to complete all its transactions:

   Replica_SQL_Running_State: Replica has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
7. stopped the SQL_THREAD of the replica
8. reset the GTID execution history and the binary log of the replica

However, there are now discrepancies between the failed primary and the new primary servers:

- **failed primary server status**:

```
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| File          | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set                           |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| binlog.000073 |      197 |              |                  | c219365c-bd04-11ed-b1e2-525400003001:1-4620 |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

- **new primary server status**:

```
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File          | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| binlog.000001 |      157 |              |                  |                   |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

We can see that the positions are different and that the new primary has no 'Executed_Gtid_Set'.
Either I missed something, or the doc is incomplete.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the issue lays within the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-solutions-switch.html):

```
On the replica Replica 1 being promoted to become the source, issue STOP REPLICA and RESET MASTER.
```

should be instead:

```
On the replica Replica 1 being promoted to become the source, issue STOP REPLICA and RESET REPLICA ALL.
```

I recreated both MySQL servers from scratch and applied the 7 steps from the first post and replaced the 8th one by:

8. Reset the replica with 'RESET REPLICA ALL;'

**On the primary before the switchover**:

```
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| File          | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set                           |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| binlog.000010 |  1380513 |              |                  | a4228b68-e5b8-11ed-ac40-525400003001:1-1615 |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

**On the new primary (former replica) after the switchover**:

```
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| File          | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set                                                                       |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| binlog.000010 |     6841 |              |                  | 61ab9e32-e5b9-11ed-b4aa-525400003002:1-511,
a4228b68-e5b8-11ed-ac40-525400003001:1-1615 |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It looks fine, except for the position which may or may not be a problem.